# Jquery nested LI elements inside tabbed content UL LI list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Im using tabbed content on my page ([SEE MY FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/timcoetzee/6dmu43b7/1/))

Now the tabbed content makes use of `<ul><li>` elements to display the different tabs. Inside one of these tabs I would like to add a `<ul><li>` list however the list is not getting displayed correctly I suspect because:

1. The jquery is effecting it
2. It is nested inside another li elements

Any idea how I can fix this?

*[please look at fiddle to fully understand my question](https://jsfiddle.net/timcoetzee/6dmu43b7/1/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`>`, child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to refine the selectors to match only the `<li>` elements immediately under `<ul id="tab">`:

```
 ul#tab > li {
     display: none;
 }
 ul#tab > li.active {
     display: block;
 }
```

```
 $("ul#tab > li:nth-child(" + nthChild + ")").addClass("active");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/63og0jue/

---

Without `>`, the selectors will match any `<li>` descendant of `<ul id="tab">`:

```
<ul id="tab">
    <li><!-- ... --></li>
    <li>
        <!-- ... -->
            <li>one</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>THree</li>
        <!-- ... -->
    </li>
    <li><!-- ... --></li>
</ul>
```

`ul#tab li:nth-child(1)`, for example, matches both of these as the first-child of their respective parents:

```
<li>one</li>
```

```
<li>
    <p>HI There Enter personal Info</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The styles affecting the li's are defined as affecting all the li's inside the #tabs container. You can add the direct descendant selector (>) to the css styles fot the tabbed menu so that these styles don't affect other li's

```
 ul#tabs {
     list-style-type: none;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: center;
 }
 ul#tabs>li {
     display: inline-block;
     background-color: #32c896;
     border-bottom: solid 5px #238b68;
     padding: 5px 20px;
     margin-bottom: 4px;
     color: #fff;
     cursor: pointer;
 }
 ul#tabs>li:hover {
     background-color: #238b68;
 }
 ul#tabs>li.active {
     background-color: #238b68;
 }
 ul#tab {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
 ul#tab>li {
     display: none;
 }
 ul#tab>li.active {
     display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, there are methods that extract text and html from lists:

```
// takes out only child html code without ul-children
jQuery.fn.justlihtml = function() {
    return $(this)  .clone()
            .children()
            .remove("ul")
            .end()
            .html();
};

// takes out only text without tags
jQuery.fn.justtext = function() {
    return $(this)  .clone()
            .children()
            .remove("ul")
            .end()
            .text();
};

var litext = $(element).justtext();
var lihtml = $(element).justlihtml();
```